# R how to add a column to a list of csv files

Tags: r

I am trying to add the name of each file in a list of .csv as the last column with all values also equal to the name. I am getting it, but the result show the files like transposed or something. I don´t know how to fix it, I have tried data.frame, unlist, but nothing.

This is the code:

```
workbooks <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names= T)

read_workbooks <- lapply(workbooks, read.csv)

for (i in 1:length(workbooks)){
  
  name_of_file[i] <- str_replace_all(str_sub(workbooks[i], 3,
                 end = unlist(gregexpr("-current",workbooks[i]))-1),"_"," ")
  
  temp_workbook <- cbind(read_workbooks[i],"Filer Name" = name_of_file[i])
  
  write.csv(temp_workbook, file = paste(name_of_file[i],".csv",sep = ""),
            row.names = F)
}
```

[image: and this is the result:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the same `lapply` call with the help of an anonymous function.

```
workbooks <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names= TRUE)

lapply(workbooks, function(x) {
  write.csv(transform(read.csv(x), file_name = basename(x)),sprintf('new_%s.csv',
        tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x))), row.names = FALSE)
})
```

Read each csv in `workbooks`, add a new column name in each file which is the name of the file and write the new csv.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I didn´t understand very well what you did, but anyway I am getting this error... Error in data.frame(list(Stock = logical(0), Symbol = logical(0), Type = logical(0),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Comment: Check all the files in `workbooks`. I think some of them are empty files hence you are getting the error.